# Are Shi’i imams really directly related to the Prophet Muhammad?

Tags: islam, iran, muhammad

Do written (or at least oral) records that show that the Shi’i imams are directly related to the Prophet Muhammad?

Comment: Muhammad died 41 generations ago; probably half the non-Muslims in the world are descended from him.

Comment: @PieterGeerkens non-muslims? That seems unlikely. Even half the muslims seems highly unlikely, considering most of them aren't even Arab.

Comment: **1:** this question should be asked in [islam.stackexchange](http://islam.stackexchange.com/questions) where they can provide you correct information about your question. **2:** You should understand first what "Imam" means, and why they only exist in shii Islam.

Comment: I think this is on-topic, and after @LennartRegebro edit it doesn't look "judging" anymore

Comment: @LennartRegebro one person can potentially have 2^40 40-generation ancestors, but I'm not sure how much this number is reduced by cousin marriages and stuff

Comment: @LouisRhys and the relentless killing of anyone who's a potential threat to your power...

Comment: @LouisRhys In the end, a lot, as people tended not to move around much. Out of 1.6 billion muslims in the world today, 1 billion are from Asia. I find it extremely hard to believe that any significant number of those are descended from Muhammad. The same goes for 250 million in sub-saharan Africa, or for that matter, North Africa.

Comment: (Although, as a tangent, one of the most successful "forefathers" of Gotland is a late 16th century priest that has at least some 20.000 offspring through history. He's my 12xgreat grandfather, giving 14 generations, which means an average factor of c:a 2.03349 per generation, meaning Muhammad with 40 generations could feasibly have as many as 2 billion descendents. But that said, I still think this sort of maths is silly and shows nothing relevant.)

Comment: Oh and enigma: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Twelve_Imams  The answer is that yes, most of the twelve Imams were **really** directly related to Muhammad. This is not under dispute.

Comment: I have (hopefully) clarified the question and voted to reopen it in its present form.

Comment: @LennartRegebro but most probably it's Shia believer who wrote that article. And probably based on Shia Islamic tradition rather than history

Comment: @LouisRhys It doesn't really matter who wrote it. Of course there exist no official government records from that time, but the writings that do exist are for the most part clear and unambiguous. There is little doubt that Hasan Ibn Ali is indeed the grandson of Muhamad. The conflict between Sunni and Shiah is about who are the true leaders of Islam, not if their were Muhammads descendants or not. Both Sunnia and Shiah accept Alī ibn Abī Ṭālib (not a descendent) and Hasan ibn Ali (Grandson) for example.

Comment: @LouisRhys This is essentially no different from disputed successions of a kingdoms somewhere. The dispute about who are the rightful king of somewhere is very rarely about who's his great-grandad was. :-)

Comment: I edited the question and removed the irrelevant parts. It is as it now stands not trivially answerable by Wikipedia, as it now asks specifically for the sources of these (generally accepted) claims that the Imams are descended from Muhammed.

Comment: and remember the claim does not set a time frame. It claims essentially that ALL imams, from the distant past to now, are all direct descendants of muhammed. Which is like claiming that all Catholic priests and nuns are direct descendants of Christ. Were anyone to make that claim nobody'd take him seriously, so why do we take this seriously?

Comment: @jwenting The largest branch of Shia Islam accepts only twelve Imams. The first of these was not a descendant of Muhammed, the rest were. The Nizari claim their current Imam is descended from Muhammed, I do not know what kind of support they have for that view.

Comment: @LennartRegebro yet pretty much every mosque has their imams, or people using that name for themselves. Maybe there's categories of imams, or multiple words in ancient arabic that are pronounced the same, or you misinterpreted the fact that shia assumes 12 original imams to mean there's only ever 12.

Comment: @jwenting That's not **Shia** imams, but Sunni Imams. The question is *specifically* about the "Shi'i Imams". http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Imam